# Outlook 2019 attachment

Tags: outlook

I want to know, if this is possible within Outlook 2019 /Office 365?

My goal is to find a solution to the following

1. Save attachments from inbox to C:\temp folder on C drive
2. Strip message details from inbox & delete the message from inbox

I guess to get this working will need a script and outlook rule to take care.  Appreciate, if anybody can help me.

Thanks

RL

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm1327)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) method of the MailItem class which saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the specified path and in the format of the specified file type. If the file type is not specified, the MSG format (.msg) is used.

To handle all incoming items you need to subscribe to the `NewMailEx` event which fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem, MeetingItem, or SharingItem. The EntryIDsCollection string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

```
Private Sub outApp_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim mail As Object
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment

    Set mail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection )

    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    sSaveFolder = "C:\Temp"
    For Each oAttachment In mail.Attachments
       oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    Next

End Sub
```

Another approach is to create a VBA sub that can be assigned to the rule. A sample VBA may look like the following one:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
  Dim sSaveFolder As String
  sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\DT168\Documents\outlook-attachments\"
  For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
  Next
End Sub
```

Read more about that in the [Automatically download Outlook attachments to folder with VBA and rule](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/3747-outlook-auto-download-save-attachments-to-folder.html) article.

Comment: Thanks Eugene,  If, I use above scripts starting with Public or Private - I cannot select the script in Outlook rule.

Comment: How can, I add another few lines to the script to delete the message from inbox after the attachment is saved?

Comment: If, I use this - Outlook rule can see the script.

Comment: Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
  Dim sSaveFolder As String
  sSaveFolder = "C:\Temp\"
  For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
  Next
End Sub

Comment: You can see the `SaveAttachmentsToDisk` sub in that case. To delete the message right after the attachment has been saved to the disk you may use the `Delete` method.

Comment: The reason for seeking help with the script is one of my user receives a lot of attachment -say about 400 per day int he form of invoice.  Don't want to save each attachment manually.  So, If, I can find a script with the rule that can save the attachment and delete the email from inbox that would be wonderful